# HttpException: Invalid response, unexpected 10 in reason phrase

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm having an issue while making an HTTP request to my router using dart. I have used `http` module as well as the `dio` both throw the same error.

I already have a `python` module for doing the same thing and it works fine. It seems like an issue in `flutter`'s `http_parser` as every HTTP request library I tried, throw the same error. An interesting thing I found is that this is not the case with the router's login route, instead, with all the other routes (`/goform/getQos`, etc).

If you have any idea how to fix this do lemme know. Here's some code.

```dart
final _client = Dio();
final response = await _client.get('http://192.168.0.1/goform/getQos?modules=onlineList');
```

Here's the exception:

```
Unhandled exception:
DioError [DioErrorType.DEFAULT]: HttpException: Invalid response, unexpected 10 in reason phrase, uri = http://192.168.0.1/goform/getWifi
#0      DioMixin._dispatchRequest (package:dio/src/dio.dart:966:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      DioMixin._request._interceptorWrapper.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:dio/src/dio.dart:849:37)
#2      DioMixin.checkIfNeedEnqueue (package:dio/src/dio.dart:1121:22)
#3      DioMixin._request._interceptorWrapper.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:dio/src/dio.dart:846:22)
#4      new Future.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future.dart:175:37)
#5      Timer._createTimer.<anonymous closure> (dart:async-patch/timer_patch.dart:18:15)
#6      _Timer._runTimers (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:397:19)
#7      _Timer._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:428:5)
#8      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:168:12)
```

**Router**: Tenda Model N301
**Flutter**: 1.22.2
**Dart**: 2.10.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon opening an issue on dart's SDK's GitHub, I was told that this is considered as the server's error where it seems to send a malformed response: finishing Status-Line with `LF` rather than `CRLF` as described in the HTTP/1.1 spec.

I will post any solution I find in this thread.

More Info:
[Github Issue](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/43916)

### Update

Dart's developers have decided to relax the HTTP Parser. This error should not occur now. [Source](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/commit/f5432d7164ca0deb1747faf910080551fd3fe280).

Answer (score 0):

This package worked for me! At the same time hope the official can be compatible

https://pub.dev/packages/sync_http

Comment: Official is now becoming compatible. This library was OK but it was synchronous.